# Creating a JavaFX TreeView using Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I'm starting working with JavaFX and wish to use the new tree view (as you can use multiple icons to represent your data - which is what I wish to take advantage of).

I have created a basic form/scene that has a tree view and one button on it. When this button is pressed I wish to populate the treeview.

Now, all the examples ive looked at are where the form/scene is generated in code and the treeview is bound to that control....how do I have a pre designed form with Scene builder and populate it from external code?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following code in a controller class. Inside the FXML file you will need to set the FXID to selectionTreeView. Tested in JDK 8u5 and it worked.

```
@FXML
TreeView selectionTreeView;
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    createTree();
}

public void createTree(String... rootItems) {
    //create root
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
    //root.setExpanded(true);
    //create child
    TreeItem<String> itemChild = new TreeItem<>("Child");
    itemChild.setExpanded(false);
    //root is the parent of itemChild
    root.getChildren().add(itemChild);
    selectionTreeView.setRoot(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the class name (including package) on the root node of your control in scene builder.  If you click on, then go to the code tab on the right it is the top field.

Now set an ID on the TreeView in your control.

Now in the controller object add a TreeView field, the variable name should be the same as what you set the TreeView ID as in scene builder.  Annotate with field with @FXML.

Now when the FXML is loaded, the controller is created and the TreeView field is set.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. It looks like im doing all of that correctly as I have double checked my code with what you have mentioned so I think the issue I have is with the scene now. My scene is loaded and set from the FXML file which has the empty treeview loaded. I have subsequently opened up the 'FXML Login Demo' from within netbeans and the scene is being refreshed by the 'replaceSceneContent' method. Looks like Ihave to refresh or re-load the scene when cahnges are made...does that seem correct?

Comment: Yes I think you will need to restart, JavaFX doesn't automatically recognise changes in FXML files and reload although you could implement something yourself to achieve that.